# Agregar marca de agua a imagen - Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, imagen, xamarin

Estoy probando un método para agregar una `marca de agua` a una imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
async void AgregarMarcadeAgua()
        {
            var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString(), "filename.png");

            Bitmap newBitmap;
            using (var aBitmapToApplyWaterMarkTo = await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(Resources, Resource.Drawable.breakingbad))
            using (var waterMarkBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(Resources, Resource.Mipmap.Icono3))
            {
                newBitmap = aBitmapToApplyWaterMarkTo.Copy(aBitmapToApplyWaterMarkTo.GetConfig(), true);
                using (var canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap))
                {
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(waterMarkBitmap, newBitmap.Width - 100, newBitmap.Height - 100, null);
                }
            }
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await newBitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fileStream);
            }
            newBitmap.Dispose();

        }
```

Pero estoy teniendo un error en esta linea, no me reconoce `Resources`

```
using (var aBitmapToApplyWaterMarkTo = await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(Resources, Resource.Drawable.imagenejemplo))
```

[image: Ejemplo]